# Function wrappers in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Why does OpenZeppelin use function wrappers?
For example:

```
function nameOfFunction() {
   _nameOfFunction();
}

function _nameOfFunction() {....}
```

I think this is for security reason but I'm not sure about my theory.

Answer (score 0):

it's for readability and ergonomics (for them). they make interfaces for most of their contracts so it's less of a pain to go about it this way.

Comment: So that's not for security reasons? I've always thought it was

Comment: Yeah haha, I mean try making a bunch of interfaces. You'll quickly see why they did this.